# Maximum tcp port number constant in java

Tags: java, tcp

Is there a public constant for the maximum TCP port number (65535) defined in java or a common library such as Apache Commons, that I could refer to from my code (instead of using the integer hardcoded)?

Comment: it's not going to change (ever) unless they redesign TCP to allow a higher port number (which isn't needed); `0xffff` is a quick way to place it down

Comment: I would create a local constant in the class where you need it.

Comment: In a word, no. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I think the question is relevant. Why would we have to define a well-known constant?

Comment: I just don't see why I have to define it myself as it is defined by an RFC (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt), and it's regarding something as broadly used as TCP, so you'd expect it to be defined somewhere common and logical. I personally expected it in java's java.net.Socket, because that one uses ports of course and out of java's own classes, it's the class that's based on TCP the most.

Comment: You could use (Short.MAX_VALUE << 1) :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm afraid there is none you can use.

Looking at the source code of Java 8 I see the following code used by the `Socket` class to verify a valid port in several functions:

```
private static int checkPort(int port) {
    if (port < 0 || port > 0xFFFF)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("port out of range:" + port);
    return port;
}
```

This can be found in `java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(int)`

As you can see Java itself doesn't use a named constant either.

A search of the code turns up the following hit in `java.net.HostPortrange`:

```
static final int PORT_MIN = 0;
static final int PORT_MAX = (1 << 16) -1;
```

But as you can see this isn't a public reference. Another private reference turns up in `java.net.SocketPermission`.

So after the inspection above, I conclude there is none available in the Java API.